# oracle sql update not working 100%

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a problem.

Here my table.

```
--tableA--

id  |   number  |   step    |   limit   |   last_update
-------------------------------------------------------
1   |   0       |   0       |   5       |   10-05-2016 08:00:00


--tableB--

id  |   number  |   step    |   last_update
--------------------------------------------
1   |   1       |   1       |   10-05-2016 08:00:00
```

Here my code.

```
for cur in
(
      select  id,number,step,limit,last_update
      from 
            tableA
)
loop 
      if cur.number < cur.limit then

            cur.number := mod(cur.number,3) + 1; --calculator cur.number increase from 1 -> 3

            insert into tableB(id,number,step,last_update) -- INSERT OK
            values (cur.id,cur.number,cur.step + 1,cur.last_update);
            commit;

            cur.step := cur.step + trunc(cur.number/3); --calculator cur.step increase by cur.number
            -- here : cur.number = 1 and cur.step = 1

            update tableA
            set 
                  number = cur.number     -- not update
                  ,step = cur.step        -- not update
                  ,last_update = sysdate  -- update ok
            where id = cur.id
            commit;

      end if;
end loop;
```

cur.number = 1 and cur.step = 1 before run update command

why tableA with id = 1 only update last_update, number and step not update.

After update tableA: number = 0, step = 0

**UPDATE CODE**

```
for cur in
(
      select  id,number,step,limit,last_update
      from tableA
)
loop 
      if cur.number < cur.limit then

            cur.number := mod(cur.number,3) + 1; --calculator cur.number increase from 1 -> 3

            insert into tableB(number,step,last_update) -- INSERT OK
            values (cur.number,cur.step + 1,cur.last_update);
            commit;

            -- cur.step := cur.step + trunc(cur.number/3); --calculator cur.step increase by cur.number
            -- here : cur.number = 1 and cur.step = 1

            select number,step into temp_number,temp_step 
            from tableB where id = cur.id;

            update tableA
            set 
                  number =  temp_number    -- not update
                  ,step = (temp_step - 1) + trunc(temp_number/3)  -- not update
                  ,last_update = sysdate  -- update ok
            where id = cur.id
            commit;

      end if;
end loop;
```

Please help me.

Thanks all.

Comment: you can't update the value of a cursor. you need to put the new values to a variable. :)

Comment: why insert success tableA with cur.number = 1 and cur.step = 1 ?.

Comment: the issue is update right?

Comment: yes, update only success last_update column. number and step not update

Comment: you're updating the values in your cursor which is readonly select and using the updated cursor values in your update query. what i'm saying is the value in cursor is readonly and you can't change it.

Comment: i declare 2 variable temp and get value from tableB with number and step column, and update 2 variable temp to tableA, but not woking.

Comment: please update your code above.

Answer (score 0):

Let see the steps:

i, you have a CURSOR, what you will open first

ii, after that you INSERTing a row:

```
        insert into tableB(number,step,last_update) -- INSERT OK
        values (cur.number,cur.step + 1,cur.last_update);
        commit;
```

iii, there is a unnecessary SELECT INTO:

```
        select number,step into temp_number,temp_step 
        from tableB where id = cur.id;
```

iv, finally the UPDATE:

```
        update tableA
        set 
              number =  temp_number    -- not update
              ,step = (temp_step - 1) + trunc(temp_number/3)  -- not update
              ,last_update = sysdate  -- update ok
        where id = cur.id
        commit;
```

The SELECT INTO is unnecessary because the values are the same in step iii, and step iv,
you are UPDATEing back the same value for the current ID.

The CURSOR is a constant resultset during the process, it wont change after an insert

Comment: if i put cursor value into stored and excute update command. TableA will update ?

Comment: yes, the table will be updated, but in that time the cursor has already readed the resultset before the update, so it wont contain the updated value